# -Wundef does not warn about an undefined symbol in front of #ifdef

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, preprocessor

Please consider the following code:

```cpp
// program.cpp

#include <iostream>

int main() {
#ifdef LINUX
    std::cout << "Linux\n";
#elif MAC
    std::cout << "Mac\n";
#elif WINDOWS
    std::cout << "Windows\n";
#elif BSD
    std::cout << "BSD\n";
#else
    std::cout << "Something else\n";
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile it with both clang and gcc,

```sh
clang++ -Wundef -DBSD -o program program.cpp
# or
g++ -Wundef -DBSD -o program program.cpp
```

I will get warnings for not defining symbols `MAC` and `WINDOWS`, but no warning for the symbol `LINUX`:

```sh
program.cpp:6:7: warning: 'MAC' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#elif MAC
      ^
program.cpp:8:7: warning: 'WINDOWS' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#elif WINDOWS
      ^
2 warnings generated.
```

According to the `gcc` man page:

```
-Wundef 
    Warn if an undefined identifier is evaluated in an "#if" directive.
    Such identifiers are replaced with zero.
```

- It says **in** an `#if` directive. Is it because the `LINUX` is not inside that structure?
- If that's the case, how can I tell compiler to emit warnings for the undefined symbol `LINUX`?

---

- `clang version 12.0.1`
- `gcc (GCC) 11.1.0`
- `Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (artixlinux)`

Comment: `#ifdef LINUX`/`#if defined(LINUX)` would have no sense if you warn for that...

Comment: Try changing `elif MAC` to `elif defined(MAC)`.  Similarly for `WINDOWS` and `BSD`.   That way your code will test if all the macros are defined, rather than (as it is now) testing if `LINUX` is defined while testing the what values the other macros expand to.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, you are right!

Comment: @Peter exactly! Without defined(MAC), it expands the symbol, and if the symbol is not defined the compiler (or preprocessor) first emits a warning, and then replace the undefined symbol with `0` so that the branch will be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that your preprocessor code asks if `LINUX` is *defined*. But for `MAC`, `WINDOWS` and `BSD` you don’t bother checking whether the symbol is defined; instead, your code *assumes* it is defined and asks for its *value*.

Change your code to use `#elif defined(…)` instead of `#elif …` to fix the warning.

Comment: So, `#ifdef` only asks whether the symbol is defined. It seems, In `#ifdef LINUX`, the symbol is not **evaluated**, so there is no warning for that. However, for the `#elif` case,  the symbol gets evaluated or compiler asks for its value! Why compiler asks for its value? Is it because `#elif` does not have any mechanism to understand it is in a `#ifdef` structure?

Comment: @Ali `#ifdef …` is simply a shortcut for `#if defined(…)`. There is no `#elifdef`, so you need to use `#elif defined(…)` instead.